# Griffon JMS plugin

Tags: java, groovy, jms, griffon

I'm starting to learn Groovy with a Client-Server architecture.

As the server I have a Grails application that contains a JMS topic. For the client I have a Griffon application, which I'd like to suscribe to that topic so it can receive messages (it would be like a push notification I think).

But I couldn't find any JMS plugins for Griffon. Does anyone exist? Ideally it should also provide a JMS provider like ActiveMQ and JNDI, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no JMS plugin for Griffon yet, at least not that I'm aware of. However building one by porting grails-jms shouldn't be that difficult. Both frameworks share a lot of code and traits that make this task an easier one.